# display table data in a list box (access form)

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I want display table data in a list box with this code:

```vb
Me.List_history.RowSource = "SELECT Date " & _
    "FROM Leaves " & _
    "WHERE CodePersonali = " & Nz(Me.CodePersonali.Value)
```

but the list box doesn't display anything

`List_history` = my list box name

`Date` = field name in `leave` table

Comment: Your table, Leaves, has data inside? Post a minimal set of data

Comment: yes, we before use this code insert data to table

Comment: Please run the query `SELECT Date FROM Leaves WHERE CodePersonali = " & Nz(Me.CodePersonali.Value) & "` and make sure data exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date` is a reserved word (it's a function), so you shouldn't use it as column name. If you must, put it between square brackets `[Date]`.

**If** `CodePersonali` is a text column, you need to put the value between `''`.

That would be

```vb
Me.List_history.RowSource = "SELECT [Date] " & _
  "FROM Leaves " & _
  "WHERE CodePersonali = '" & Nz(Me.CodePersonali.Value) & "'"
```